# ¿Como obtener parte de un grupo de datos que se repite una sola vez y que el resto se repita en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Posee las siguiente tablas:

```
inspection -----------------------------------
Columna Tipo            Nulo    Predeterminado  
id_inspection           int(9)  No           
machines_numbers        int(1)  No           
shift_shifts_id         int(9)  No           
group_groups_id         int(1)  No           
sample_samples_id       int(1)  No           
line_lines_id           int(1)  No           
elaborated_employer_id  int(6)  No           
auditored_employer_id   int(6)  Sí  NULL         
approved_employer_id    int(6)  Sí  NULL 
--------------------------------------------

inspections_shapes_registers------------
Columna Tipo              Nulo          
id_isr  int(9)            No             
creation_date_f           varchar(255)               
creation_date_nf          varchar(255)               
inspection_inspections_id int(9)                     
sr_shapes_registers_id    int(9)         
---------------------------------------

shapes_registers----------------------
Columna Tipo            Nulo    
id_shape_register       int(9)                   
data                    varchar(1000)    
machine_machines_id     varchar(1)       
st_shapes_templates_id  int(9)
--------------------------------------
```

Para mostrar los datos basandome en una fecha y linea utilizo la siguiente query:

```
SELECT i.id_inspection, 
                       i.machines_numbers, 
                       sr.data,
                       isr.id_isr, isr.creation_date_f, isr.creation_date_nf,
                       s.description as shift_description,
                       g.description as group_description,
                       sa.description as sample_description,
                       l.description as line_description,
                       st.name as shape_description,
                       e.id_card
            FROM       inspections_shapes_registers AS isr 
            INNER JOIN inspections                  AS i 
            ON         isr.inspection_inspections_id = i.id_inspection 
            INNER JOIN shapes_registers AS sr 
            ON         isr.sr_shapes_registers_id = sr.id_shape_register
            INNER JOIN shifts as s
            ON         i.shift_shifts_id = s.id_shift       
            INNER JOIN groups as g
            ON         i.group_groups_id = g.id_group
            INNER JOIN samples as sa
            ON         i.sample_samples_id = sa.id_sample
            INNER JOIN lines_ as l
            ON         i.line_lines_id = l.id_line  
            INNER JOIN shapes_templates AS st 
            ON         st.id_shape_template = sr.st_shapes_templates_id
            INNER JOIN employees AS e 
            ON         i.elaborated_employer_id = e.id_card
            WHERE 
                isr.creation_date_nf = :inspectionDataDate
                AND i.line_lines_id = :inspectionDataLine
                AND i.shift_shifts_id = :inspectionDataShift
```

Lo que obtengo:

```
1
5
{"inspection1111"}
1
2018-02-22 10:01 AM
2018-02-22
1er
A
Primera Muestra
A1
qq-1244
1233

1
5
{"inspection2222"}
2
2018-02-22 10:01 AM
2018-02-22
1er
A
Primera Muestra
A1
qq-1244
1233

1
5
{"inspection3333"}
3
2018-02-22 10:01 AM
2018-02-22
1er
A
Primera Muestra
A1
qq-1244
1233

1
5
{"inspection4444"}
4
2018-02-22 10:01 AM
2018-02-22
1er
A
Primera Muestra
A1
qq-1244
1233

1
5
{"inspection5555"}
5
2018-02-22 10:01 AM
2018-02-22
1er
A
Primera Muestra
A1
qq-1244
1233
```

Lo que quisiera obtener, pues solo varia en ella el valor del sr.data (`{"inspection1111"}`)  y del id.isr valor seguido a el (`{inspection}`), pero el segundo no importa mucho, sino obtener los datos que se repiten una sola vez, es decir todos los sr.data (`{inspection}`):

**Resultado:**

```
1
5
{"inspection1111"}
{"inspection2222"}
{"inspection3333"}
{"inspection4444"}
1
2018-02-22 10:01 AM
2018-02-22
1er
A
Primera Muestra
A1
qq-1244
1233
```

**Relaciones**

Cada registro de **INSPECTIONS**
se le asocia multiples **SHAPES_REGISTER**
verificando que tengan su **ID**.
cada `{"inspection"}` es un `DATA` que le corresponde a un **SHAPES_REGISTER**

**Actualización** 3:37pm

**Nota:** Los valores para sr.data pueden superar los 1000 caracteres al concatenarse juntos. Me aparece incompleto el resultado

**Resultado de la respuesta de @Marcos**

```
1
5
{"inspection1111"}
{"inspection2222"}
{"inspection3333"}
{"inspection4444"}
{
1
2018-02-22 10:01 AM
2018-02-22
1er
A
Primera Muestra
A1
qq-1244
1233
```

Comment: ¿La cantidad de `{"inspection***}` puede cambiar? Si es así, ¿como podrías saber cuantas son las columnas que necesitas leer? ¿Agruparlos es una opción? Es decir, ¿te puede servir que en una columa todos los `sr.data` separados por coma por ejemplo?

Comment: @Marcos lo que dices, si me serviria, porque quiero mostrar los datos de la inspeccion una vez y luego para ella TODOS los sr.data

Comment: @Marcos el resto de los datos aunque se repiten NO varian, en cambio los sr.data si

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En base a [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140542/como-obtener-parte-de-un-grupo-de-datos-que-se-repite-una-sola-vez-y-que-el-res/140559#comment262674_140542), para agrupar los registros puedes usar [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) combinándolo con [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Por lo que se puede ver, necesitas agruparlos todos aquellos que tienen el mismo `i.id_inspection`. Sino indicas como hay que agruparlos, podría no ser el esperado.

Así por ejemplo:

```
SELECT i.id_inspection, 
         i.machines_numbers, 
         # Agrupamos todos los `sr.data` en la columna `data`
         GROUP_CONCAT(sr.data SEPARATOR ',') AS data,
         isr.id_isr, isr.creation_date_f, isr.creation_date_nf,
         s.description as shift_description,
         g.description as group_description,
         sa.description as sample_description,
         l.description as line_description,
         st.name as shape_description,
         e.id_card
    FROM       inspections_shapes_registers AS isr 
    INNER JOIN inspections                  AS i 
    ON         isr.inspection_inspections_id = i.id_inspection 
    INNER JOIN shapes_registers AS sr 
    ON         isr.sr_shapes_registers_id = sr.id_shape_register
    INNER JOIN shifts as s
    ON         i.shift_shifts_id = s.id_shift       
    INNER JOIN groups as g
    ON         i.group_groups_id = g.id_group
    INNER JOIN samples as sa
    ON         i.sample_samples_id = sa.id_sample
    INNER JOIN lines_ as l
    ON         i.line_lines_id = l.id_line  
    INNER JOIN shapes_templates AS st 
    ON         st.id_shape_template = sr.st_shapes_templates_id
    INNER JOIN employees AS e 
    ON         i.elaborated_employer_id = e.id_card
    WHERE 
        isr.creation_date_nf = :inspectionDataDate
        AND i.line_lines_id = :inspectionDataLine
        AND i.shift_shifts_id = :inspectionDataShift
    # Indicamos que queremos agrupar los registro que tengan el mismo `i.id_inspection`
    GROUP BY i.id_inspection
```

El resultado debería ser el siguiente:

```
1
5
{"inspection1111"},{"inspection2222"},{"inspection3333"},{"inspection4444"}
1
2018-02-22 10:01 AM
2018-02-22
1er
A
Primera Muestra
A1
qq-1244
1233
```

Comment: El id.shape_register, si cambia, pues para cada sr.data existe una fila con un id.shape_register distinto, si elimino esa parte al final de group by, funciona genial. Si la dejo los registros se repiten como estaba al principio, a pesar de tener el GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: Ya coloque el group by, no veo cambios, pero es justo lo que necesitaba. ¿podrias explicar que diferencia habria si no coloco el group by?

Comment: @vaavDev, he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Excelente y satisfecho :)

Comment: Hermano, me surgio un problema, a la hora se obtener los data, al final se le agrega una llave { (final: cuando se agrupan todos los datos), por lo que luego no puedo convertilos a ARRAY usando json_decode

Comment: Al parecer superar los 1024 caracteres por lo que concatenado no se muestra completo, que puedo hacer?

Comment: @vaavDev, en efecto el limite por defecto es de `1024` caracteres. Si lees la documentación (_ver enlace en la respuesta_) dice que para aumentar el limite se debe cambiar el valor de la variable `group_concat_max_len`. Por ejemplo `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;`

Answer (score 0):

Para terminar de completar la respuesta, en mi caso los string de inspection podian llegar hasta 2000 caracteres concatenados.

Utilice esto:

```
$setting = "SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000";
```

Para configurar el tamaño del largo del GROUP_CONCAT